# How to combine these two functions in python

Tags: python, class, for-loop

I currently have created this code in python. The output is exactly what I want. (If you know of a better way to get it, I am open to hear). I want to know how I can combine my functions triangle and triangle2 into one main function. (My output is a sideways pyramid).

```
def triangle(n): 
   for x in range(n):
        print ('*'*x)
        n = n - 1 

def triangle2(n): 
   for x2 in range(n):
        print ('*'*n)
        n = n - 1

height = int(input("Enter an odd number greater than 4: "))

triangle(height)
triangle2(height)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def triangle(n):
   for x in range(n):
        print ('*'*x)
   for x in range(n):
        print ('*'*n)
        n -= 1

height = int(input("Enter an odd number greater than 4: "))

triangle(height)
```

Comment: The first loop *doesn't need to alter `n`*; it is *not used there*. As such you don't need to create a copy in `tmp` *either*.

Comment: this is what i picked

Answer (score 1):

Just put the two loops together into one function, but don't alter `n` until the second loop (the first doesn't use it anyway):

```
def sideways_pyramid(n): 
   for x in range(n):
        print('*' * x)

   for x in range(n):
        print('*' * n)
        n = n - 1
```

You can avoid altering `n` altogether by counting down with the `range()` instead:

```
def sideways_pyramid(n): 
   for x in range(1, n):
        print('*' * x)

   for x in range(n, 0, -1):
        print('*' * x)
```

The second loop counts down, starting at `n` and ending at 1. I also start the *first* loop at 1, to not print an empty first line (0 times `'*'` is an empty string)

Demo:

```
>>> def sideways_pyramid(n): 
...    for x in range(1, n):
...         print ('*' * x)
...    for x in range(n, 0, -1):
...         print ('*' * x)
... 
>>> sideways_pyramid(5)
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it as close to your original Code as possible:

```
def triangle2(n): 
       for x2 in range(n):
            print ('*'*n)
            n = n - 1    

def triangle(n): 
       for x in range(n):
            print ('*'*x)
       triangle2(n)  

height = int(input("Enter an odd number greater than 4: "))

triangle(height)
```

You can just call your other function from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to run them both in the order specified at the bottom I would do something like this:

```
def triangle(n): 
    for x in [y for y in range(n)] + [z for z in range(n, 0, -1)]:
        print("*"*x)


height = int(input("Enter an odd number greater than 4: "))

triangle(height)
```